# Handle big Stored Procedure results

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm working on a Windows service that runs once per day. The service is for merging data from an external database to my database. The problem is that I only have access to the external database with stored procedures.

When I use one of those stored procedures it returns 1.2 million objects and my service's RAM usage rises up to 2.5GB.

FYI: I'm using EF 6 with DB first for the external database and code first for my database.

GetArt() in the following method is one of the stored procedures that the entity framework created and it returns 1.2 Million objects.

```
public List<GetArt_Result> GetArtls()
    {
        List<GetArt_Result> results = new List<GetArt_Result>();
        using (ExternalContext context = new ExternalContext()) {
            results = context.GetArt().ToList();
        }

        return results;
    }

public void SaveArticles(List<GetArt_Result> externalArtls)
    {
        try {
            List<Article> artls = new List<Article>();
            foreach (var artl in externalArtls) {
                artls.Add(new Article(artl));
            }
            using (DbContext context = new DbContext()) {
                context.BulkInsert(artls);
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

How can I handle 1.2 million objects without high RAM usage?

Comment: alternatively, you could look into pure DB solutions, like running procedures on your DB from the windows service and those SPs would call the procedures on the external

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this scenario, your best bet is probably to try to use a non-buffered reader API so that you don't need to buffer all the objects in memory at once. I don't know what `context.GetArt()` returns, but if this is *already* `IEnumerable<T>`, then it is *possible* that you already have access to this; you can then iterate over that data (`foreach`) to do whatever you need to, without ever having to have all the data in memory at once. If the `GetArt()` method *doesn't* provide this: then it might be possible to use an alternative API. For example, with "dapper" this could be `Query<T>` specifying the optional `buffered: false` parameter (it defaults to `true`, as this is fine for most use cases).

Note, however, that the key point here is: you can't throw them into a `List<T>`. The moment you do that - it needs buffering. Likewise, operations like `OrderBy` (when applied to sequences, not queries): causes buffering.